# Read cell value & replace Alt+Enter with a ,

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am using Apache POI api to get data from a cell which is of type string but the value is separated by Alt+Enter.

1. He
2. this
3. ***"is\nthis\nA\ntest"***
4. a
5. test

The highlighted text is one cell containing value with Alt+Enter(shown as \n). I want to read this data replace "\n" or Alt+Enter with , and then use the value 
i.e. output I want after replacing \n is: is,this,A,test

The code used by me is given below:

```
String data = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            System.out.println("output:"+data);
                            if(data.contains("\n")){
                                sb.append(data.replace("\n", ","));
                            }else{
                                sb.append(data);
                            }
                            //sb.append(myValue);
                            sb.append('|');
```

Here sb is the stringbuffer in which I append the data.
The data in StringBuffer object sb is then written to a csv file with pipe as delimiter.
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: do you know how to retrieve the value of a cell?  Do you know how to set it to a new value?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to use the Cell object and get the string value from it..

Comment: Show us some code.  We want to know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: String data = cell.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println("output:"+data);
        if(data.contains("\n")){
         sb.append(data.replace("\n", ","));
        }else{
         sb.append(data);
        }
        //sb.append(myValue);
        sb.append('|');

Comment: do not put code here, update your question, and tell me what output you get.  And what is sb?  If it's a StringBuffer, you need to dump its contents somewhere like cell.set...(sb.toString())

Comment: the output I expect is = "is,this,A,test" but I am getting it as 4 new entries

Comment: You're not showing enough code on how you are interfacing with your csv output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did almost everything right.

1. If the comma still would be a field separator too, you must place the data between double quotes (which is the general convention). Or better exclude the usage of comma as separator.
2. If instead of the `\n` (LF) there is a CR+LF `\r\n` then `\r` might have been recognized as record terminator.

I cannot entirely read from your description what is the case.

The following does both things. And checks.

```
       if (data.contains("\r")) {
           System.out.println("CR found");
       }

       sb.append('\"')
           .append(data.replace("\r?\n", ","));
           .append('\"');
           .append('|');
```

An `if` is not necessary, and `StringBuilder` is a bit faster than the older `StringBuffer`.